# How to convert a text line in text box in MS CRM 2011 to hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, textbox, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I already have code which is given below

```
var input = document.getElementById("documentlink");
input.style.color = "blue";
input.style.textDecoration = "underline";


input.onclick = function () {
   if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("documentlink").getValue() != null)
        window.open(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("documentlink").getValue());
}
```

but the problem here is I cannot use html DOM since it can become an issue in upgradation as custom code validation tool identifies textDecoration as an issue.
I cannot make that text box format to URL as that gives absolute URL and I am not allowed to change the types of existing fields.
If there is any method to do this then please help.

Comment: In Dynamics CRM a text field can be formatted as a URL. This format type must be chosen when creating the field and cannot be modified afterwards. Can't you use that approach?

Comment: No I cannot use that approach as that gives me absolute URL and I want ralative URL. Second thing is its already a text field and as you said it cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are a lot of ways to accomplish your goal:

1. You can add ribbon button by clicking on which url would be opened.
2. You can create your custom html webresource what can store/read information in/from your field and has required formatting. Shortly about development of Html/Js webresources and embedding it to your crm form you can read here - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2015/03/howto-htmljs-webresources.html